# How to check if a list of ids exists in db without fetching the count and compare it to the list count

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I know this sounds like a duplicate question, but what I want is slightly different from other answers.
Technically I want to get this query sent to the database using Linq:

```
Select Count(*) = 3 From Products Where Id in (1,2,3)
```

Notice this query returns True if all ids exist, and False if any of them doesn't.
It is kind of `Products.Exists(p => ids.Contain(p.Id))` but all the ids should exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] ids = new int[] { 1, 3, 9, 11, 125 };
bool res = ids.All(id => Products.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(id));
```

Comment: This is brilliant, sorry for the late reply. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a great answer because it will result in separate queries for every id in the array.

A better solution would be something like this:

```
var ids = new int[] { 1, 3, 9, 11, 125 };
var res = Products.Count(s => ids.Contains(s.Id)) == ids.Length;
```

This will result in just one query using the IN clause.